# Discord.JS: How to create permanent and infinite uses invite?

Tags: node.js

I have a bot that sends partner to my server's partner channel. The invites that the bot creates must be permanent and infinite uses. How can i do that?

My code to create an invite:

```js
let invite = await message.channel.createInvite({
  maxAge: 86400000, //1 day
  maxUses: 1
}).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Using `maxAge:0`  and `maxUses: 0` ? More info in the doc https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-channel-invite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the max values provided in the discord.js docs:

```
let invite = await message.channel.createInvite({
  maxAge: 0, // 0 = infinite expiration
  maxUses: 0 // 0 = infinite uses
}).catch(console.error);
```

[Discord createInvite() Docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=createInvite)